# Extracting table data from unevenly spaced text file

Tags: python, ubuntu, awk, sed, text-processing

```
         CLASS RECORD OF THE STUDENT FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH WHO TOPPED
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender   
Anna (+)            USA        A1          First (100)      Female
(04)                California V
ADDITIONAL RECORDS OF THE STUDENTS FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH NEXT IN LIST
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender
Bob (-)             USA        A2          First (99)       Male
(07)                Florida    VI
Eva (+)             USA        A4          Second (96)      Female
(12)                Ohio       V           English (99)
                                           Maths(100)
Other records are not available currently.Some records may be present which can be given on request.
```

Getting the text file from a PDF using **pdftotext**. Using below **AWK** command I am getting the above data.

Table data is **unevenly space separated**. 

 Remove the lines where the **whole line** is in **Uppercase**

 Remove all the **last lines** after the table content.

```
pdftotext -layout INPUTFILE.pdf INPUTFILE.txt
awk '/RESULTS/{flag=1;next}/OTHER DATA/{flag=0}flag' INPUTFILE.txt | column -ts $'\t' -n
```

---

How do I get the table data in tab delimited format(*Below Format*)?

Code in a generic way, so it works other types of tables also.

```
Name (Roll no) #    Location    Section     Rank (MARKS)    Gender  
Anna (+)            USA         A1          First (100)     Female
(04)                California  V
Bob (-)             USA         A2          First (99)      Male
(07)                Florida     VI
Eva (+)             USA         A4          Second (96)     Female
(12)                Ohio        V           English (99)
                                            Maths (100)
```

Comment: Have patience!!! @Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I present here is an `awk` one. In which I will make the following assumptions :

- The header-line `Name (Roll no) ... Gender` could appear multiple times
- The list under the header-line has a fixed field-width, but the fieldwidth is unknown. I assume this from the line with `California` in it, as that word only has a single space behind it.
- After each header-line, the fieldwidths can change.

In `awk` we can set a fixed field width using the internal variable `FIELDWIDTHS`:

> **`FIELDWIDTHS #`** A space-separated list of columns that tells gawk how to
>   split input with fixed columnar boundaries. Starting in version 4.2,
>   each field width may optionally be preceded by a colon-separated value
>   specifying the number of characters to skip before the field starts.
>   Assigning a value to `FIELDWIDTHS` overrides the use of `FS` and `FPAT` for
>   field splitting. See [Constant Size](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) for more information.
>
> **note:** this is a `gawk` extension

To determine the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable, we will make use of `match` and `RSTART`:

> **`RSTART`** The start index in characters of the substring that is matched
>   by the `match()` function (see [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions)). `RSTART` is set by
>   invoking the `match()` function. Its value is the position of the string
>   where the matched substring starts, or zero if no match was found.

Thus this gives us already the following (note `OFS` is set to `|` to demonstrate the correct working behaviour)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
     /^[- A-Z]*$/{next}          # skips only caps lines
     /Other records might/{next} # skips the last line
     /^Name.*$/{                 # find header line
       match($0,"Location");i2=RSTART;
       match($0,"Section"); i3=RSTART;
       match($0,"Rank");    i4=RSTART;
       match($0,"Gender");  i5=RSTART;
       FIELDWIDTHS= i2-1" "i3-i2" "i4-i3" "i5-i4" 6"
       $0=$0                     # reprocess header line
       # print header line only the first time
       if (v==0) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}
       v++; next      
     }
     {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

This already outputs

```
Name (Roll no) #    |Location   |Section     |Rank (MARKS)     |Gender
Anna (+)            |USA        |A1          |First (100)      |Female
(04)                |California |V||
Bob (-)             |USA        |A2          |First (99)       |Male
(07)                |Florida    |VI||
Eva (+)             |USA        |A4          |Second (96)      |Female
(12)                |Ohio       |V           |English (99)|
                    |           |            |Maths(100)|
```

**comment:** at this time it already looks "OK", but take into account that the columns don't need to be the same width after each header-line (assumption 3).

You wanted a tab-delimited column system, however tabs are evil. Everything depends on how your system interprets how wide a tab is. Is it `4`, `8` or `17`. I present here a space delimited system. The best is to remove all spaces from the end of each field and then use the command `column`. This leads to :

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
     /^[- A-Z]*$/{next}          # skips only caps lines
     /Other records might/{next} # skips the last line
     /^Name.*$/{                 # find header line
       match($0,"Location");i2=RSTART;
       match($0,"Section"); i3=RSTART;
       match($0,"Rank");    i4=RSTART;
       match($0,"Gender");  i5=RSTART;
       FIELDWIDTHS= i2-1" "i3-i2" "i4-i3" "i5-i4" 6"
       $0=$0                     # reprocess header line
       # print header line only the first time
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/ *$/,"",$i);
       if (v==0) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}
       v++; next      
     }
     {
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/ *$/,"",$i);
       print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5
     }' <file> | column -t -s '|'
```

This outputs :

```
Name (Roll no) #  Location    Section  Rank (MARKS)  Gender  
Anna (+)          USA         A1       First (100)   Female  
(04)              California  V                              
Bob (-)           USA         A2       First (99)    Male    
(07)              Florida     VI                             
Eva (+)           USA         A4       Second (96)   Female  
(12)              Ohio        V        English (99)          
                                       Maths(100)
```

Remark that `column` will adjust the columns as needed, so they do not necesarily have the same width every time. If you know the column width, I suggest to use the `printf` statement in `awk` which would then be :

```
awk 'BEGIN{format="%-18s%-12s%-9s%-14s%-6s\n"}
     /^[- A-Z]*$/{next}          # skips only caps lines
     /Other records might/{next} # skips the last line
     /^Name.*$/{                 # find header line
       match($0,"Location");i2=RSTART;
       match($0,"Section"); i3=RSTART;
       match($0,"Rank");    i4=RSTART;
       match($0,"Gender");  i5=RSTART;
       FIELDWIDTHS= i2-1" "i3-i2" "i4-i3" "i5-i4" 6"
       $0=$0                     # reprocess header line
       # print header line only the first time
       if (v==0) {printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}
       v++; next      
     }
     { printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }' <file>
```

with as output:

```
Name (Roll no) #  Location    Section  Rank (MARKS)  Gender
Anna (+)          USA         A1       First (100)   Female
(04)              California  V                            
Bob (-)           USA         A2       First (99)    Male  
(07)              Florida     VI                           
Eva (+)           USA         A4       Second (96)   Female
(12)              Ohio        V        English (99)        
                                       Maths(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the extracted data is in fixed-width format after removing the unwanted lines. You may try

```
txt = """CLASS RECORD OF THE STUDENT FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH WHO TOPPED
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender   
Anna (+)            USA        A1          First (100)      Female
(04)                California V
ADDITIONAL RECORDS OF THE STUDENTS FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH NEXT IN LIST
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender
Bob (-)             USA        A2          First (99)       Male
(07)                Florida    VI
Eva (+)             USA        A4          Second (96)      Female
(12)                Ohio       V           English (99)
                                           Maths(100)
Other records are not available currently.Some records may be present which can be given on request"""

data = [[line[:20], line[20:31], line[31:43], line[60:]] 
        for line in txt.split('\n')[1:-1] if line != line.upper()]    # add .strip() if you want to remove the white space at beginning and the end
del data[3]   # Remove the header for additional records

>>> for line in data:
...     print(line)

# ['Name (Roll no) #    ', 'Location   ', 'Section     ', 'Rank (MARKS)     ', 'Gender   ']
# ['Anna (+)            ', 'USA        ', 'A1          ', 'First (100)      ', 'Female']
# ['(04)                ', 'California ', 'V', '', '']
# ['Bob (-)             ', 'USA        ', 'A2          ', 'First (99)       ', 'Male']
# ['(07)                ', 'Florida    ', 'VI', '', '']
# ['Eva (+)             ', 'USA        ', 'A4          ', 'Second (96)      ', 'Female']
# ['(12)                ', 'Ohio       ', 'V           ', 'English (99)', '']
# ['                    ', '           ', '            ', 'Maths(100)', '']
```

Comment: You can't append two items at once. And its not in fixed width format

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to correct the line to remove header, edited.